# Not receiving serial logs on lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I have installed lubuntu on intel i386 32 bit machine .Installation is successful but when i connect to ttyS9 port using putty it get connected but didn't receive any data.I have already added user to dialout group. When i run the dmesg | grep ttyS command I can see all the ports but no data is coming on any port.As i can see the devices in /dev directory so I suppose it has all the drivers available and should get some data on the port.I am not able to find what i need to change in order to get the data .Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get data from serial port now , its just I added user to root group also and it started working.Thanks...

Comment: It is really strange again I am facing same issue and getting no logs.Please suggest